# how to give fixed table rows using typescript

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

I am using table for showing the datas and for data I am using Api.

Api data looks like::

```
{
 "data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "name1",
        "label": "label1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "name2",
        "label": "label2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "name3",
        "label": "label3"
    }
   ]
}
```

html code

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Label</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of sample;">
        <td>{{data.id}}</td>
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.label}}</td>
      <tr>
    <tbody>
   <table>
```

[image]

I need the 10 table rows statically(fixed). The table data is from API. For exanple ,Api contains 2 data... Then UI table should be with 2 rows of data and balance with emply rows... but there should display 10 rows(Mandatory)

which means in UI i want 10 rows with data from Api and balance should be empty.

Comment: What is the exact question regarding the implementation for the desire result? You want to fix the table as 10 row? Then where is the "balance" come from?

Comment: I need the 10 table rows statically(fixed).  The table data is from API. For exanple ,Api contains 2 data... Then UI table should be with 2 rows of data and balance with emply rows... but there should display 10 rows(Mandatory)

Comment: Are you looping row or using third-party component of library for table ?

Comment: not using any libraries for table.. Now I edited the question, there I gave the table html code which I used

Comment: you want ten rows in all even if data from API is more or less. right?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix in view layer, ts layer or even backend API layer (Not really recommended).

In view layer if you loop over your data, you can calculate if your data's size goes over arbitrary threshold and if not loop again to display as many empty rows as possible.

In ts layer, when you receive data from api you can modify variable you pass to your view by adding to an array as many empty items as you need. 
What's important if you use null, then you have to check for it with for example elvis operator.  
I would advise agains adding to an array an object with all properties set to null, because then these are not so easily distinguishable from valid data from API and you can for instance make some rows interactive, even though they should not be.

```js
const dataFromApi = [{ "id": "1", "name": "name1" }, { "id": "2", "name": "name2" }]
const minRowsNumber = 10;
const diff = minRowsNumber - dataFromApi.length;
const viewTableData = diff > 0 ? dataFromApi.concat(new Array(diff).fill(null)) : dataFromApi;

console.log(viewTableData)
```

Example in AngularJs (No Angular in SO Snippets, but it is the same principle)

```js
angular.module('example', [])
.controller('ExampleController', function ExampleController() {
    const dataFromApi = [{ "id": "1", "name": "name1" }, { "id": "2", "name": "name2" }]
    const minRowsNumber = 10;
    const diff = minRowsNumber - dataFromApi.length;
    this.viewTableData = diff > 0 ? dataFromApi.concat(new Array(diff).fill(null)) : dataFromApi;

});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="example" ng-controller="ExampleController as example">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in example.viewTableData track by $index">
        <td>{{row ? row.id : '&nbsp;'}}</td>
        <td>{{row ? row.name : '&nbsp;'}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```